# Potential repercussions to applying to lots of jobs?

Tags: job-search, job-change

I'm wondering what potential issues I could encounter if I apply to a lot of jobs. I personally love applying to as many jobs which fit my specific criteria, but since this minimum criteria is quite low (pay, location, required skills), is there any repercussions I could be neglecting/blinded to from this job hunting strategy?

I have *personally* found most of my jobs by applying to as many jobs as I possibly can which fit my minimum criteria. I find having an interview helps immensely for deciding if a position is a good fit rather than only researching. I was wondering if there could be potential issues with applying to too many jobs. The jobs I have had have all been quite decent and I tend to find work quite quickly from this approach (even though the process can be hectic if poorly managed).

If I'm already looking for a job anyway, could applying to a ton of jobs cause issues for me? If so, stating why and what appropriate number you think to apply to would rock. I am mainly interested to confirm my suspicion.

Comment: Do you want to burn bridges with so many companies?

Comment: Job hunters often apply to dozens of jobs at a time. Your motivations and reasons for doing so don't matter. I don't see what "negative repercussions" you'd imagine other than potentially experiencing writers cramp, carpal tunnel syndrome, or eye strain from reading so many job descriptions and filling out so many online and paper applications.

Comment: @solarflare, I've only found companies have shown gratitude towards me applying for their role. I'm literally going through the process of showing how I'm interested in working with them - if the process doesn't work out, I have yet to see push back. I've ended up getting jobs from other companies by expanding my network from this process.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, Thanks! I agree and will continue to do so (since I have found this method works quite well)

Comment: @joeqwerty, I agree. This technique for job hunting has almost always worked in my favour. I find it takes much more work on my end but leaves me with a much better job at the end of the process.

Comment: Why would a company you applied to know anything about how many other applications you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Potential repercussions to applying to lots of jobs?

If you apply for 10 jobs, and get 10 offers, then you can professionally decline 9 offers and take the best one. The companies will understand that this is only your business decision, and you have to watch for your best interest.

Nevertheless, the 9 companies, whose offers you decline, may not be too eager to interview you again so soon after you decline their offers because they would think that you are much happier with other companies.

---

One down size with having too many interviews at different companies is that you may have to spend a lot of times to do the interviews. For example, some big tech companies normally have 4 or 5 technical interviews for 1 software engineer position, and each interview lasts for 1 hour. It will consume lots of your time and energy in this way.

However, this may only depend on the industry you are in.

In some other industries, you may only need to have 1 or 2 quick interviews per job.

Answer (score 4):

> I am mainly interested to confirm my suspicion

So you have your own reasoning you think this might be bad, but you're withholding from including it in your question....? It would be easier for people to confirm/correct your suspicion if you told them what it was.

As for your question, the only thing I can think of is if you want to someday apply for a job at a company you apply to now. If they contact you for a follow-up this time and you're so busy or already got a new job that you ghost them, it could hurt your reputation. Or if they reject one of your throwaway applications for qualification or job fit reasons, their system *might* reject you automatically next time. I doubt this happens often, if ever, but I suppose a possibility.

On the other hand, having a positive interview experience but no job from it might help your network for next time and could make it easier to get a job in the future. So net-net you'd probably come out ahead as long as you don't apply to so many jobs that you end up ignoring a lot of their responses.

Comment: confirm my suspicion that I am correct ;)

Comment: I think ghosting is always a bad idea. Overall, I've found my network has grown from the endevours rather than diminished. Each other job tends to understand and I stay in contact with them after the fact to see how their hunt ends up going; this has also gotten me jobs as well if the job I took ends up being a bad fit.